# Are continuous mixtures of the gamma distribution identifiable with respect to the scale parameter?

Tags: bayesian, parameter-estimation, gamma-distribution, mixing

Consider the two-parameter Gamma($\alpha$,$\beta$) distribution with PDF

$$f(x|\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} \exp(-\beta x)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}, \quad x>0, \alpha>0, \beta>0,$$

where the scale parameter, $\beta$, can have any of a number of continuous prior distributions with PDF $g_i(\beta), \beta > 0$.

My question is:

For fixed $\alpha$, is the mixture PDF,

$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x|\alpha,\beta) g_i(\beta) d\beta, \quad x>0,$$

identifiable with respect to $\beta$?

In other words, does $$\int_0^\infty f(x|\alpha,\beta) g_j(\beta) d\beta = \int_0^\infty f(x|\alpha,\beta) g_k(\beta) d\beta, \quad x>0 \qquad (1)$$

imply $$g_j(\beta) = g_k(\beta), \quad \beta>0?$$

I've looked for this result (or its negation) extensively, but with no luck.  The closest thing I've found is a discussion of the identifiability of Gamma($\alpha$,$\beta$) mixtures with regard to the $\alpha$ parameter (for fixed $\beta$), which Maritz and Lwin (*Empirical Bayes Methods with Applications*) show are identifiable because Gamma($\alpha$,$\beta$) is an additively closed family with respect to $\alpha$.

Thanks in advance for any references or suggestions!

Addendum:  I should have noted that for $\alpha = 1$ (i.e., the Exponential($\beta$) case), the mixture PDF,

$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x|\alpha = 1,\beta) g_i(\beta) d\beta,$$

*appears* to be identifiable if the Laplace transforms of the $g_i(\beta)$ are well defined in a neighborhood of $0$.  This is because Eq. (1) (and successive derivatives of both sides WRT $x$) can be used to show that all raw moments associated with $g_j(\beta)$ and $g_k(\beta)$ are identical (which unfortunately doesn't imply that the two PDFs are the same).